# How can I check my object type is Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If I write something like this:

```
var img = $(new Image()).attr('src', image.src);
```

How can I check later if img var is an image and not something else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 if ( img.is('img') ){

 }
```

for safety I may be tempted to wrap the var in jQuery again just incase you may have changed the img to a dom node or something else...

```
if ( $(img).is('img') ){

}
```

Comment: Is there a pure Javascript way to do this?

Comment: try if (img.nodeType === 1 && img.tagName === "img")

Answer (score 1):

```
img.filter('img')
```

If this returns something then it is an image.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid explicit type checking.

Use polymorphism to select what has to be done with images, and what has to be done with other objects.

```
var img = $(new Image())(...);
img.process = function(){ ... do whatever images need ... };
objs.push( img );

var txt = new Text();
txt.process = function(){ .. do text processing, spellcheck, ... };
objs.push( txt );

...

objs.each( o ) { o.process(); }
```

Comment: I'm using some gallery code and its an ugly code. sometimes img means Image object, sometimes its just an html code (flash EMBED or something) and it should only run some code i've written if img == Image object.